# What are some things that could destory humanity?

Tags: humans, apocalypse, futurology, extinction

I trying to think of ideas for the destruction of humanity/civilization that are not the usual (nuclear war, extreme viral/deadly disease, global warming, overpopulation, etc). Something that would be rather unexpected.

It doesn't have to neccesarily be something that kills everything. It could just break down civilization, set humanity back thousands of years or permanently cripple humanity from future progess (i.e. debris in orbit around earth that prevents humans from leaving earth).

Just trying to find some interesting and unique ideas for this.

Comment: Welcome to worldbuilding. Please take a good read at our [help], you will find that we don't do brainstorming or idea generation, we rather solve well defined problems. Can you formulate your problem in such a way?

Comment: Hi @Lee Morgan, I'm voting to close as the question is essentially asking for us to give you your story. Although the community is more than happy to help iron out circumstance and details, we can't give you plot points. I might recommend coming up with a few separate ideas and asking individual questions about their plausibility.

Comment: You're asking for a long if not endless list, and without further detail an opinion based one at that, two solid VTC reasons in one, with a little stretching we could call it three 

Comment: Eat drink and be merry - tomorrow it'll be a ruin.

Answer (score 1):

### [Brood parasites](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brood_parasite).

Humans lived for a long time in a condition of ad hoc symbiosis with their working animals.  Dogs hunted, cats moused, chickens laid eggs.

But animals *evolved* within this niche.  They became *cute*.  They became *pets*.  They began to provide *emotional support*.  With each neotenic mutation, they came to resemble human infants more closely.  Saying a dog was a member of the family became a joke ... then not a joke.  Pet ownership increased, and birth rates declined.  More and more people never had *human* children.  Beyond evolution, cultural factors came in to play: it was seen as *better* to collect money for homeless animals than for homeless people.  Parents didn't even seem *fit* to have children without proving they could take care of a pet first.

And all that was before AI could simulate animals with "deepfake" resolution!  Before entrepreneurs selling genetically modified animals could screen thousands of people in focus groups, to see exactly which features of an AI-generated animal most pull at their heartstrings (and their wallet strings).  Before a host of new breeds contained the very best features of dozens of breeds generated by traditional artificial selection, with none of the drawbacks imposed by bottlenecks during their selective process.

By the time the world ended, there was no more tolerance for traditional human relationships.  Bearing children was seen as imposing a misery - a flawed species incapable of feeling or causing happiness to anyone.  There was no room for anyone to even *think* of comparing the brood parasites of other species to the best friends that humans now proudly called their owners and masters.  As the last few clusters of aging humans made their final sacrifice to the planetary ecology, they were tormented by only one worry: that the robotic assistants they had left might not always be able to repair themselves sufficiently to be able to serve the pets left behind.

Comment: Well, at least it was a cute answer for a doomed, dying question. You could see the end coming, but were somehow compelled to take it seriously anyway...